# SAX parser returns null

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser

I am trying to parse an online XML document but when I run the following code, it returns a NULL Exception in the `get()` method. I tried debugging further to realise that inputstream maybe returning a null value.  Anyone know whats wrong?

```
public class XMLHelper extends DefaultHandler{

private String URL_MAIN = "https://www.ura.gov.sg/LsmMap/xml/lsm-test.xml";

String TAG = "XMLHelper";
Boolean currTag = false;
String currTagVal = "";

private PostValue post ;

private ArrayList<PostValue> postsList = new ArrayList<PostValue>();


//to read the XML
public void get() {
    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser mSaxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader mXmlReader = mSaxParser.getXMLReader();

        mXmlReader.setContentHandler(this);

        InputStream mInputStream = new URL(URL_MAIN).openStream();
        mXmlReader.parse(new InputSource(mInputStream));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception123: " + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Remove unnecessary lines from the code that you've added here. Post minimal code to understand the problem. Also add stack trace/ error details to the problem.

Comment: Absolutely. In particular, the message and stack trace from the exception you catch (with the weird comment "*But, this is about XML Parsing not about Exception Handling*") would be very helpful here.

Comment: @BalkrishnaRawool removed excess codes

Comment: I just tried to run your code. It works fine. BTW you could still get rid of the unused variables. And you haven't added any error message/ stack trace.

Comment: error message shown was a null exception in this class for the get() method.